# My $.getJSON doesnt seem to be retrieving the information from my JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My json file is called data.JSON, and it's in the same directory as my index.html and my js file.

In the html I have linked the jquery, then the js file.

The data in data.JSON is:

```
[
{
    "question": "What OS does the One Plus One run by default?",
    "choices": ["Android 5.0 Lollipop", "Cyanogen Mod 11", "Android Kitkat", "iOS", "Cyanogen Mod 11"]
},
{
    "question": "Who is the lead singer of the British band 'Muse'?",
    "choices": ["Matt Bellamy", "John Lennon", "Will.I.Am", "Danny O'Donoghue", "Matt Bellamy"]
},
{
    "question": "Which Japanese/American singer released 'Goodbye Happiness'?",
    "choices": ["Jay Park", "Utada Hikaru", "Gackt", "Yoshika", "Utada Hikaru"]
},
{
    "question": "The popular Korean girl-group known as 'Girl's Generation' is also known as:",
    "choices": ["4Minute", "SNSD", "After School", "Girl\'s Day", "SNSD"]
},
{
    "question": "What sub-genre of EDM does the hit 'Selfie' fall under?",
    "choices": ["Melbourne Bounce", "Big House Boom", "Dubstep", "Grime", "Melbourne Bounce"]
}
]
```

The javascript file I'm linking contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';
var allQuestions;

$.getJSON("data.json", function (info) {
       alert("hi"); 
    });
});
```

The actual problem I'm getting is that I cannot even seem to get the alert to pop up. All I want to do is to the load data from my JSON into my JS file so that I can run the quiz script, but I'm having troubles just getting the JSON loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you serving your JSON file from a web server? If not, if you have python installed go to the folder where your data.json file exists and write `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, then go to your browser and point it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.json and voila.

Comment: You can add something like .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) { }); To see what the specific error is.

Comment: `(document).ready` should be `$(document).ready` if that's not a typo.

Comment: I see that it was :)

Comment: My JSON file is local, everything im using is local atm, including the jquery. I don't have python installed sadly, haven't learnt any python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this so you actually get to see the fail reason:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("data2.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err.responseText);
    })
});
```

However the fact that you ain't getting to the alert makes me think that there's another error in your code. Check your debugging tools.

Comment: I tried this, and it skips the console.log of the data, and runs the console.log in the .fail(). The console.log in the .fail() returns the whole JSON object array, maybe it's a problem with my JSON formatting?

Also, my JSLint shows no errors in my js file

Comment: Wait, `"Girl\'s Day"` comes as bad string. You should remove the \ from it.

Comment: This worked! I can get the alert to show, so I can proceed with messing around now! Thanks a lot, I was pulling my hair out over this small little thing for a large portion of today! =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying this is a modern browser, I am afraid to tell you that AJAX calls won't work. Google Chrome creates this error message, when page is served locally:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

What this means is you need a server to make ajax calls, using `getJSON` function. To get a simple server setup, install python and use it's SimpleHTTPServer module, as suggested by @limelights.

Once python is installed, open terminal/command prompt and `cd` to folder where your `html` file is. Then type in the commmand `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. This gives you simple server access over `localhost:8000`. And now the script runs just fine.

*Note*: Make sure that there's some text in the JSON file, or else it won't work.

Comment: What makes you think that he doesn't have a web server? Or that he wants a Python one. Did you just copy paste this answer from another place without bothering to read the question?

Comment: well, he's written, 'cannot even seem to get the alert to pop up' and I was able to replicate the situation only by accessing the page locally. But when I accessed it via python server, it worked.
The one thing that I did overlook, however, is that there's a `'\` character in one of the JSON entries. My test json file was normal.
So even if he were to try what i suggested, it still wouldn't have worked.

PS: I did bother to read the question.